# Reflection error when creating an instance of a form

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I've been experimenting with an application that will scan an assembly, check for any classes that are forms and then see what members they have.

The code I'm using to query the assemblies is:

```
 Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);

 Type[]  types = testAssembly.GetTypes();
 textBox1.Text = "";

 foreach (Type type in types)
 {
     if (type.Name.StartsWith("Form"))
     {
         textBox1.Text += type.Name + Environment.NewLine;

         Type formType = testAssembly.GetType();
         Object form = Activator.CreateInstance(formType);       
      }
 }
```

I'm using this to query a standard form:

```
 using System;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace TestForm
 {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
         public Form1()
         {
            InitializeComponent();
         }
     }
 }
```

My problem is that when the code tries `Activator.CreateInstance(formType)` I get an exception stating: `"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."`
I can also see from checking formType that 'DeclaringMethod: 'formType.DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException''

I don't understand the error message as the form has a standard constructor, am I missing something really obvious?

EDIT : `type.Name` reveals the type that the code is trying to instantiate as being `Form1`.

Comment: Are you *sure* that's the type which is failing, and not some other type whose name starts with `Form`?

Comment: type.Name.StartsWith("Form") - not the best way to check whether this type is a form

Comment: @JonSkeet - I'm not sure what other type could be, the assembly I'm querying a standard Windows Form project created in VS2010.

Comment: @username - Duely noted, this is only test code at the minute, I'll look at formalising that part when I've got the main bit running.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush: Well you should be able to see from the text box, which should have displayed the name of the type it's about to create an instance of...

Comment: I think with this approach, you need to make sure that you have a default constructor (i.e. parameter less constructor) on every form that is contained in that assembly.

Comment: @JonSkeet - The textbox returns "Form1" as the type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to create an instance of Assembly, not of your form:

```
     Type formType = testAssembly.GetType();
     Object form = Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
```

You should do:

```
     Object form = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

BTW, I wouldn't use the name of the class to check if it is derived from Form, you can use IsSubclassOf:

```
     type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form));
```

Comment: Aha, bingo! Well spotted. It's not clear what use `formType` is meant to be serving at all...

Comment: All that fuss and it was a typo, well spotted Francesco, thank you. I was basing my code on a couple of examples I'd found and it looks like I'd made a mistake entering it.

Answer (score 1):

Object form = Activator.CreateInstance(**type**);